# Is it possible to add derive annotations when generating Diesel models via diesel_cli_ext?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am using [diesel_cli_ext](https://github.com/abbychau/diesel_cli_ext) to generate Rust model code:

```
diesel_ext --schema-file src/model/diesel/dolphin/dolphin_schema.rs --model > src/model/diesel/dolphin/dolphin_models.rs
```

The generated model looks like this:

```rust
#[derive(Queryable, Debug)]
pub struct AdminUser {
    pub id: i64,
    pub nickname: Option<String>,
    pub avatar_url: Option<String>,
    pub phone: Option<String>,
    pub updated_time: Option<i64>,
    pub created_time: Option<i64>,
    pub salt: Option<String>,
    pub pwd: Option<String>,
    pub sex: Option<i32>,
    pub level_type: Option<String>,
    pub phone_region: Option<String>,
    pub country_code: Option<i32>,
    pub user_status: Option<String>,
}
```

Is it possible to add more annotations when generating the model? I'd like to have these derives:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Queryable, Deserialize, Default)]
```

I have been adding it by myself, but the next generation overwrites the previous modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the ["how to use" documentation](https://github.com/abbychau/diesel_cli_ext#how-to-use) shows that a command line option allows you to modify the `derive`s:

```
    -d, --derive DERIVES
                        set struct derives
```

There's also an [issue for per-table derive modifications](https://github.com/abbychau/diesel_cli_ext/issues/31).